# How to limit the occurrence of a value in rows when insert with multi threads

Tags: mysql

I am facing a situation where I want to limit occurrence of a value in rows. For example, I want the maximum appearance of value `V` through the records in table T to be 5. Any insert statement that inserts `V` into the table after 5 should be rejected.

With single threading manner, I can check if the occurrence of `V` is less than 5 or not before inserting. But when insertions are conducted with multi threads, e.g. 100 threads, the application logic can be broken.

One solution is lock the table before any insert statement, however, it might not an optimal solution. Please share to me if you have any idea, thanks.

Update: Example

I have a table named `persons` with 2 columns `(id, name)`

[image]

Currently, the value `Anna` appears in 4 records. There are two threads trying to insert other `Anna`s into the table at the same time. How to take just one and reject the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the check with the insert so they happen simultaneously:

```
insert into mytable (name)
select 'Anna'
from (select 1) x
where (select count(*) from mytable where name = 'Anna') < 5
```

Relational databases are [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), which in this case means that if two such queries are run simultaneously, because they are operating on the same entity, they will effectively be forced to be sequential operations (not concurrent), so one transaction will complete before the other, and the other will "see" the data written by the first and so determine the count as 5.

Comment: But, could you briefly explain how does it help? Did it acquire X lock of the table or selected rows?

Comment: @TaQuangTu explanation added. Also read the [wiki article on ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), which thoroughly explains the phenomenon.

Comment: How did the combination make a transaction wait for others to complete? As far as I know, `select` statement on the same entities concurrently is allowed in MySQL InnoDB, they share an `S` lock for reading the entities.

Answer (score 0):

hope triggers can help, check [SIGNAL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html):

```
drop trigger table_trigger_test;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER table_trigger_test
BEFORE INSERT ON table_trigger
REFERENCING NEW AS new

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE b INT;
    SET b = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_trigger where name = new.name);
    IF (b >3)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'over 4';
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there a chance both the threads count `b`==4 (that satisfies the condition) then insert successfully?

Comment: I probably missed that; it's probably not appropriate in a situation with multiple threads.

Comment: I believe there is performance issue, right? Every insertion causes a count(*) action, I think normally I would keep track of the count in somewhere else like an atomic counter, for example redis

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I think, but leveraging an outside system for this task is one of my last considerations.